# How to maintain checkBox value on collectionView scroll

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, collectionview

When I scroll following collection view, checked checkbox is getting unchecked. Doing some research I've found that the views associated to the items are reused during the scroll. How can I maintain original value?

```
    <CollectionView 
        x:Name="LvSospesi" 
        ItemsSource="{Binding ListaSospesi}" >

        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="model:SospesoModel">
                <Grid 
                    x:Name="GridSospesi" 
                    IsEnabled="{Binding BindingContext.ListaSospesiEnabled, Source={x:Reference RootPage}}">
                    
                    <!--IsEnabled="{Binding Source={x:Reference LvSospesi}, Path=SelezioneInCorso, Converter={StaticResource notConverter}}">-->

                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="40"/>     
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <CheckBox 
                        x:Name="ChkSeleziona" 
                        Grid.Column="0" 
                        Grid.Row="0" 
                        IsChecked="{Binding Selezionato}">

                        <CheckBox.Behaviors>
                            <behaviors:EventToCommandBehavior EventName="CheckedChanged"
                                Command="{Binding BindingContext.CheckSospesoCommand, Source={x:Reference RootPage}}"                            
                                CommandParameter="{Binding .}"/>
                        </CheckBox.Behaviors>
                    </CheckBox>

                    <!-- removed for simplicity -->

            </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    </CollectionView>
```

This is the itemsSource model:

```
public class SospesoModel : BaseModel
{
    public Scadenza ScadenzaCliente { get; set; }
   
    public bool Selezionato { get; set; }  
}
```

Comment: I don't know much about Xamarin but usually if you do data binding correctly it will work because Selezionato property will change according to the checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

- `SospesoModel` or `BaseModel` must implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`. Does it inherit from some class or interface that does so?
- bound properties must do `OnPropertyChanged();`:

```cs
public bool Selezionato {
    get => _selezionato;
    set { _selezionato = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
}
```